# Ruby regex gsub change within backreference

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find and amend each  tag in an array using the following:

```
re = /(?<img><img .*? \/>)/
my_string.gsub re, '\k<img>'
```

Thi successfully matches all image tags properly and I can add content before and after the backreference, but is there away to add something within? (i.e. when I want to add attributes to the tag?)

Thank you.

Comment: you could add a capture group for attributes

Comment: See https://ideone.com/XSo5EL

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use capturing groups like this:

```
my_string = "<img src=\"\" />"
re = /(<img .*?)\s*(\/>)/
puts my_string.gsub re, '\1 more="here"\2'
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/XSo5EL).

**Details**

- `(<img .*?)` - Group 1 later referred to as `\1`: `img`, space and any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\/>)` - Group 2 (`\2`): a `/>` substring.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a match group inside of the `<img>` tags and extract the attribute that way, then do your work on that.
Not sure if you can use `gsub` for that, but `match` is pretty powerful as well, you can read about it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html). If you use match against a string, it will return a `MatchData` class object whose elements you can access using the `[]` method. The elements of this object are all the matches that are made, in the example below, those are the whole string and all the attributes on their own.

Back to your question, [here](https://regex101.com/r/dewo3i/1)'s an example on regex101 in which you can see how you would do the matching of each specific attribute you're looking for.

How this turns out in the end is as follows.

```
re = /<img( src=\".*?\")?( alt=\".*?\")?( height=\".*?\")?( width=\".*?\")?(\/|\ \/)?>/

test = '<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">'

matches = test.match(re)

matches
# => #<MatchData "<img src=\"smiley.gif\" alt=\"Smiley face\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\">" 1:" src=\"smiley.gif\"" 2:" alt=\"Smiley face\"" 3:" height=\"42\"" 4:" width=\"42\"" 5:nil>
matches[0]
# => "<img src=\"smiley.gif\" alt=\"Smiley face\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\">"
matches[1]
# => " src=\"smiley.gif\""
matches[2]
# => " alt=\"Smiley face\""
# ...
```

Comment: The problem is I want to add an attribute that doesn't exist, and I do not want to lose any other attributes that may or may not exist :/

Comment: You could the use the whole match, from the `matches[0]` and add something before the `>` or `/>` at the end, or even concatenate all of the attribute matches into a whole new string with `<img>`.